# Change default action for copying files to external hard disk

Tags: macos, external-disk, copy-paste

The default behaviour on Mac OS when you move files from your machine to an external device is to copy these files. How can I modify this behavior so it moves the files, rather then making copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move a file rather than copying to another volume (network, external drive, etc.) by simply holding the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key down while dragging the file.

If you are on the samve volume (EG you want to *copy* to another folder) hold down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key will dragging and that will copy a file from any location to any other location *on the same volume.*